# Condition on the inequality holds asymptotically

Tags: asymptotics

$$(n-1) \left[\frac{1}{2}\log\left(\frac{1}{2p}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\log\left(\frac{1}{2(1-p)}\right)\right]>2\log(n)$$

where $p$ is a function of $n$.

How to find out on which condition of $p$ such that the inequality holds (asymptotically)?

From the following experiment, it seems when $p>\frac{1+\sqrt{\frac{2\log n}{n}}}{2}$ the inequality holds, and when $p<\frac{1+\sqrt{\frac{2\log n}{n}}}{2}$ the inequality does not hold.

I can manage to prove that this is true by plugging the form of $p$ as $\frac{1+\sqrt{\frac{a\log n}{n}}}{2}$ into the inequality, but I have no idea to prove it without assuming the form of $p$.

It would be much appreciated if someone could help me out. Many thanks in advance!

[image]

[image]

Comment: It is a quadratic equation of $p$, right?

Comment: @RiverLi I don't get it, could you rephrase? there is no equation for $p$.. only inequality for $p$.

Comment: How about $(n-1) \left[\frac{1}{2}\log\left(\frac{1}{2p} \cdot \frac{1}{2(1-p)}\right)\right] > 2\log(n)$, or $p(1 - p) < \cdots$?

Comment: @RiverLi yes, i see, so it should be $p(1-p)<\exp(-\frac{2\log n}{n-1}-\log 4)$, but then i don't know how to proceed

Comment: WLOG, assume that $p \ge 1/2$. For an inequality $p (1 - p) < c$, you have $p > \frac12 + \frac12\sqrt{1 - c}$. Then you analyze asymptotic properties of $\frac12 + \frac12\sqrt{1 - c}$.

Comment: @RiverLi Thank you! I arrived at $p>\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{1-\exp(-4\frac{\log n}{n-1})}$. But I don't know how to align this with what we expect: $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{2\log n}{n}}$

Comment: I wrote something as an answer. You can try to prove that $1 - \mathrm{e}^{- \frac{4\ln n}{n - 1}} \le \frac{4\ln n}{n}$.

Comment: By the way, I think the result should be $p > \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{4\log n}{n}}$ rather than $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{2\log n}{n}}$.

Comment: @RiverLi According to the simulation in my post, it should be $\sqrt{\frac{2\log n}{n}}$..

Comment: How about $n = 10^6$, solve the original inequality, we have $p> 0.5037168727$. (1) $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{2\log n}{n}}$ gives $0.5026282609$; (2) $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{4\log n}{n}}$ gives $0.5037169222$.

Comment: When $n = 10^{12}$, solve the original inequality, we have $p> 0.5000052565$. (1) $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{2\log n}{n}}$ gives $0.5000037169$; (2) $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{4\log n}{n}}$ gives $0.5000052565$.

Comment: Have you gotten clear which one is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $n>1$, gouping terms, you look for the problem of
$$-\log (p(1-p) )~~ \geq~~ \frac{4 \log (n)}{n-1}+2 \log (2)= A$$ When $n$ increases, the solution requires that $p$ just be above the root of $\text{(lhs - rhs)}=0$ which is closer an closer to $p=\frac 12$.

Expanding as a Taylor series, we have
$$\text{(lhs - rhs)}=-\frac{4 \log (n)}{n-1}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {t^n} n \qquad \text{with}\qquad t=(2p-1)^2$$ that is to say
$$\text{(lhs - rhs)}=-\frac{4 \log (n)}{n-1}-\log (1-t)=0$$
$$t=1-n^{-\frac{4}{n-1}}\qquad \implies\qquad p=\cdots$$

**Edit**

To better see my point, type in Wolfram Alpha

`Plot[-2*Log[2]-(4*Log[10])/(10-1)-Log[p(1-p)],{p,0,1}]`

and look where the expression is positive. Change the $10$ by the number you want.

Comment: Thanks! but then how to get $p>\frac{\sqrt{2\log n/n}+1}{2}$?

Comment: could you also elaborate "When $n$ increases the solution requires that $p$ just be above the root of (lhs-rhs)=0"? thank you very much.

Comment: @M.K. I made an edit to my answer

Answer (score 0):

**Some thoughts.**

The inequality is written as
$$p(1 - p) < \frac14\mathrm{e}^{- \frac{4\ln n}{n - 1}}. \tag{1}$$

WLOG, assume that $p \ge 1/2$. (1) is equivalently to
$$p > \frac12 + \frac12\sqrt{1 - \mathrm{e}^{- \frac{4\ln n}{n - 1}}}.$$

We can prove that, for all $n \ge 2$,
$$1 - \mathrm{e}^{- \frac{4\ln n}{n - 1}} \le \frac{4\ln n}{n}.$$

Thus,
if $p > \frac12 + \frac12\sqrt{\frac{4\ln n}{n}}$, then the original inequality is true.